# Writing generated JSON to file, BabyParse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

I'm using BabyParse to convert a local CSV file to JSON. Here's the `js` file I've written that does it:

```
var Baby = require('babyparse');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'test2.csv';
var content = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: 'binary' });

parsed = Baby.parse(content, {fastMode: false});
rows = parsed.data;
console.log(rows);

fs.writeFile("blahblahblah.json", rows, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

The JSON outputted to the console by the `console.log(rows)` line seems to be correct(ish). However, when I write `rows` to a file, all the JSON boilerplate disappears. For example, here's what I get when trying to convert the following csv file:

```
col1,col2,col3
"val1","val2","val3"
"val1","val2","val3"
"val1","val2","val3"
```

This is what gets printed to console:

```
[ [ 'col1', 'col2', 'col3' ],
  [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
  [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
  [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ],
  [ '' ] ]
```

But this is what gets written to the file:

```
col1,col2,col3,val1,val2,val3,val1,val2,val3,val1,val2,val3,
```

Does anyone know what's happening here? Why is the JSON-specific syntax being stripped out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your json into a string before you save it.

```
rows = JSON.stringify(parsed.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick!

```
fs.writeFile("blahblahblah.json", JSON.stringify(Baby.parse(content, {fastMode: false}).data), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
```